# jq map first level key to a nested value

Tags: json, jq

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), how can I transform an input to a JSON object which maps the first level keys to the value of the `latest` nested value? For example, given the input

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "current": "0.15.14",
    "wanted": "0.15.14",
    "latest": "0.16.4",
  },
  "bar": {
    "current": "8.27.0",
    "wanted": "8.27.0",
    "latest": "8.29.0",
  },
  "baz": {
    "current": "27.1.5",
    "wanted": "27.1.5",
    "latest": "27.1.6",
  }
}
```

How can it be transformed to

```json
{
  "foo": "0.16.4",
  "bar": "8.29.0",
  "baz": "27.1.6"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map all field values to their `.latest` field, either by using `map_values`

```bash
map_values(.latest)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mtuuA76MpZM)

Or by updating `|=` each field `.[]` with that filter

```bash
.[] |= .latest
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7a_GQVm12-t)

Actually, `map_values(f)` is just a [defined shortcut](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L33) for `.[] |= f`.